# PHPMailer Invalid address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send a mail with [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/). I use this code, but I got this error :

> Invalid address: example@gmail.com

(I use fake addresses for StackOverflow. I use a real address in my real code.)

```
<?php

    $from = "My Name";
    $mail = "example@gmail.com";

    require_once('./class.phpmailer.php');

    $bodytext = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 style='text-align:center'>Some text</h1>
    <p>more text. Here's a name : $from</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
    try {
        $email = new PHPMailer(true);
        $email->From      = 'webmaster@mysite.com';
        $email->FromName  = 'WebMaster';
        $email->isHTML(true);
        $email->Subject   = 'subject';
        $email->Body      = $bodytext;
        $email->addAddress( $mail, "Name" );
        $email->AddReplyTo($mail,"Name");

        // $file_to_attach = $filePath;

        // $email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'constat.pdf' );

        $email->Send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    // var_dump($email);
?>
```

Sice there is already a SMTP server running, I don't have to configure it, and the PHP function `mail` is working.

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Check the return value from `addAddress`, and also look in your mail server log.

Comment: I already did. It returned `false`, and since I get the error without trying to send the mail (I removed the line), I don't think there is anything in the logs.

Comment: Well that's your answer then - you are giving it an invalid address.

Comment: It is not an invalid address. Even when I use my real mail address (Gmail), I got the same error.

Comment: Well if you insist on making life hard for yourself... Cut your code back to a minimal example, stick some 'echo' statements in validateAddress so you can see what it's doing. This is very basic debugging.

Comment: It's very simple - look *inside* validateAddress to see *why* it's returning `false`. There is either something wrong with your address, or the validation. Do you have error output turned up (`E_ALL`) on your PHP config? I use PHPStorm, though any IDE will give you a lot more help than a generic editor.

Comment: I don't display all errors. And I don't want to use PHPStorm. Notepad++ was always enough.

Comment: Fine, so look inside validateAddress, see which pattern it's choosing and see what doesn't match your address.

Comment: I don't know how to use regular expressions, and they are too long for me to understand them. I tried some websites to check the regular expression, and 2 of them are telling that the address match the regular expression, and the 2 other tells it's not.

Comment: Which one is it selecting? And which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.5, and I since I don't know which regular expression the string match, I don't know which case he selected... Do you want the PHPMailer file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79658/discussion-between-synchro-and-seblor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Actually, there is a problem with the regular expression which is checking if the mail address is valid when the pattern selected is `pcre8`. I changed it to

```
/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
```

And it's working now.

Thanks @Synchro.