# invalid puny Encode while trying to send email using stmp configuration

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm trying to send a mail using stmp configuration but it always displays a puny encode invalid error . I'm guessing it's my validation method that has a bug when the `prce8` is selected ( i'm using php5  so it selects as best choice pcre8). I have already checked on that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639192/phpmailer-invalid-address) but still does not work !

```
   <?php
require_once('class.mail.php');
$to=isset($_POST['verify'])?$_POST['verify']:false;
$subject="TSHED Email verification";
$message='<html><p> my message </p></html>';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

 // SMTP Configuration
 $mail->SMTPsecure='ssl';
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com "; // SMTP server
 $mail->Username = "myEmail";
 $mail->Password = "mypassword";            
 $mail->Port = 465; // optional if you don't want to use the default 

 $mail->From = "<FromanEmail>";
  $mail->FromName = "Name";

  $mail->Subject = $subject;
 //$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
  $mail->isHTML($message);
   $mail->Body=$message;
   $mail->msgHTML($message);

   // Add as many as you want
  $mail->AddAddress($to,'USER');
 if(!$mail->Send())
   { //echo"endterer";
    $response = "Message error!".$mail->ErrorInfo;
   echo $response;
    echo $to;
      }

    else {
      $response = "Message sent!";
       echo $response;
    }


    ?>
```

Any Help Please ?
 my pcre8:

```
          case 'pcre8':
return (boolean)preg_match(
                '/^(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){255,})(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){65,}@)' .
                '((?>(?>(?>((?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[\t ])+|(?>[\t ]*\x0D\x0A)?[\t ]+)?)(\((?>(?2)' .
                '(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?3)))*(?2)\)))+(?2))|(?2))?)' .
                '([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]))*' .
                '(?2)")(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?4))*(?1)@(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?>([a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)' .
                '(?>(?1)\.(?!(?1)[a-z0-9-]{64,})(?1)(?5)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?6)){7}' .
                '|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){8,})((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,6})?::(?7)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?6)(?>:(?6)){5}:' .
                '|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?8)?::(?>((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}' .
                '|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?9)){3}))\])(?1)$/isD',
                $address
            );
```

exemple of valid Email: ouedson0128@yahoo.fr

Error :Invalid address: (punyEncode)

Comment: Please post example data and full text of the error.

Comment: I edited to give an example of valid Email and the error displayed

Comment: What version of PHP and PHPMailer are you using? There were some problems with some PCRE libraries in some releases of PHP 5.5.

Comment: PHP: 5.6.19 PHPMailer:5.2.16 @Synchro

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a bug in phpMailer. Try another version